# How to run Sequelize migrations inside Docker

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

I'm trying to docerize my NodeJS API together with a MySQL image. Before the initial run, I want to run Sequelize migrations and seeds to have the tables up and ready to be served.

Here's my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services: 
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: myuser
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    networks:
      - app-connect
    volumes: 
      - db-config:/etc/mysql
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./db/backup/files/:/data_backup/data
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: node-mysql-app
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    ports:
      - '3030:3030'
    networks:
      - app-connect
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
volumes: 
  db-config:
  db-data:
networks:
  app-connect:
      driver: bridge
```

Here's my app's `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3030
ENV PORT 3030
ENV NODE_ENV docker
RUN npm run db:migrate:up
RUN npm run db:seeds:up
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

And here's my `default.db.json` that the Sequelize migration uses (shortened):

```json
{
  "development": {
    
  },
  "production": {
    
  },
  "docker": {
    "username": "myuser",
    "password": "mypassword",
    "database": "mydb",
    "host": "mysqldb",
    "port": "3306",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

Upon running `compose up` the DB installs well, the image deploys, but when it reaches the `RUN npm run db:migrate:up` (which translates into `npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`) I get the error:

```
npx: installed 81 in 13.108s

Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.17.0, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.6.2]

Loaded configuration file "default.db.json".
Using environment "docker".


ERROR: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mysqldb
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
```

If I change the `"host"` in the `default.db.json` to `"127.0.0.1"`, I get `ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306` in place of the `ERROR: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN mysqldb`.

What am i doing wrong, and what host should I specify so the app can see the MySQL container? Should I remove the network? Should I change ports? (I tried combinations of both to no avail, so far).

Comment: I hope i can help. I found something similar here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60916919/docker-compose-unable-to-connect-to-mysql-app-builds-before-mysql?fbclid=IwAR2A8W0I6gSE4t8V8pYEWZgKzVAmd5fXqnOJzx5XxLKaJ4qPKzE00swo2-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue by using [Docker Compose Wait](https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait). Essentially, it adds a wait loop that samples the DB container, and only when it's up, runs migrations and seeds the DB.

My next problem was: those seeds ran every time the container was run - I solved that by instead running a script that runs the seeds, and `touch`s a semaphore file. If the file exists already, it skips the seeds.

Comment: Could you share how you made it work?

Answer (score 3):

The following configuration worked for me, I am adding the .env, sequelize configuration along with mysql database and docker. And finally don't forget to run **docker-compose up --build** cheers

**.env**

```
DB_NAME="testdb"
DB_USER="root"
DB_PASS="root"
DB_HOST="mysql"
```

**.sequelizerc** now we can use *config.js* rather than *config.json* for sequelize

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.js')
}
```

**config.js**

```
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  development: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: "mysql"
  },
  test: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: "mysql"
  },
  production: {
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: "mysql"
  }
}
```

**database-connection with sequelize**

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import dbConfig from './config/config';

const conf = dbConfig.development;

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  conf.database,
  conf.username,
  conf.password,
  {
    host: conf.host,
    dialect: "mysql",
    operatorsAliases: 0,
    logging: 0
  }
);

sequelize.sync();

(async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    console.log("Database connection setup successfully!");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Unable to connect to the database", error);
  }
})();

export default sequelize;
global.sequelize = sequelize;
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  proxy:
    name: proxy

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb
    healthcheck:
      test: "mysql -uroot -p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD  -e 'SHOW databases'"
      interval: 10s
      retries: 3
  api:
    build: ./node-backend
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /api
COPY . /api
RUN npm i
EXPOSE 3000
RUN chmod +x startup.sh
RUN npm i -g sequelize-cli
RUN npm i -g nodemon

ENTRYPOINT [ "./startup.sh" ]
```

**startup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

npm run migrate-db
npm run start
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a really clean solution wanted to share it. First of all I used docker-compose, so if you are using only docker, it might not help.
First thig first, I created a docker file which looks like that.I am using typescript, so if you are using js, you don't need to download typescript and build it!

```
FROM node:current-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
COPY .env.development ./.env


RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g typescript

RUN npm install -g sequelize-cli
RUN npm install -g nodemon

RUN npm run build
RUN rm -f .npmrc

RUN cp -R res/ dist/
RUN chmod 755 docker/entrypoint.sh
EXPOSE 8000

EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 9229
CMD ["sh", "-c","--","echo 'started';while true; do sleep 1000; done"]
```

Till here it is standart. In order to do things in right order, I need a docker compose and entrypoint file. Entrypoint file is a file, that runs when your containers start. Here is docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.development
    entrypoint: docker/development-entrypoint.sh
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    env_file:
      - ../.env.development
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      
  
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
    volumes:
      - ./docker_postgres_init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/docker_postgres_init.sql
```

As you can see, I am using postgresql for db. My docker file, docker-compose and also entrypoint files are in a folder called docker, thats why the paths starts wtih docker, change it according to your file structure. Last and the best part is the entrypoint file. It is really simple.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Starting get ready!!!"
sequelize db:migrate
nodemon ./dist/index.js
```

Ofcourse change the path of the index.js file according to your settings.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward method is to execute the migration using your script.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run migrate-db && node index.js"
  }
```